# Strange error from apache trying to bind to an unspecified IP

Tags: apache-2.2, routing, nat, virtualization

I am getting a strange error message from Apache when I try to start the server

```
.

     * Restarting web server apache2                                                apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
[Thu Jan 10 17:49:32 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost 122.174.238.1XX:0 has no VirtualHosts
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
[Thu Jan 10 17:49:32 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost **122.174.238.1XX:0** has no VirtualHosts
(99)Cannot assign requested address: make_sock: could not bind to address 122.174.238.1XX:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
                                                                         [fail]
```

The strange thing is I have no idea where it is getting 22.174.238.1XX IP from

I have one file in sites-enabled :

```
   <VirtualHost 192.168.1.90:80>
DocumentRoot "/home/webmaster/www/thefaXXXX"
ServerName thefaXXXXX.cu.cc
<Directory "/home/webmaster/www/thefaXXXXX">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My hosts file in /etc/  reads

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       NightHwack
192.168.1.90    thefaXXXX.cu.cc
192.168.1.90    www.thefaXXXX.cu.cc
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I wnat my server to listen on 192.168.1.90 at port 80.
I tried deleting the virtual server with webmin and creating a new one that listens on192.168.1.90 (without server names etc) but still get exactly the same error.

I can't understand where apache is picking up the 122.*.*.* IP from

Comment: Please check `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`

Comment: yeh it had that IP inside it, removed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a static IP defined inside `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`. Reconfigure the file to fix the problem.